# Unexpected Error for My Interests and Newsfeed Settings

Tags: error, my-site, newsfeed

While accessing My Site -> My Interests and Newsfeed Settings, I am getting this error:

```
Error 
An unexpected error has occurred. 
Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 
Correlation ID: ee7ff5fe-feed-472e-add8-639424410447 
Date and Time: 4/8/2010 2:23:31 PM
```

However the My Site -> My Colleagues option work well.

Anybody faced this problem before?

Environment: SP2010 Server on Windows 2008.
I am using Administrator ID to login to the site.

Digged the LOGs and found this:

```
04/08/2010 14:33:14.55  w3wp.exe (0x0828)                           0x1AFC  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Web.HttpException: **Multiple controls with the same ID 'ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ProfileEditorValueAccountName' were found**. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.    at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)     at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)     at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)     at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable(Control namingContainer, ControlCollection controls)     at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.AsSeenBy.GetEffectivePrivacy(Page page)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControl... 4015c593-b9b1-4141-815e-82fc55777208
04/08/2010 14:33:14.55* w3wp.exe (0x0828)                           0x1AFC  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...s.MySitePublicWebPartPage.GetEffectivePrivacy(Page page)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileUI.IsViewableByMe(ProfileSubtypeProperty prop)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileUI.LoadProfileTable()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileUI.LoadControl(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMai...  4015c593-b9b1-4141-815e-82fc55777208
04/08/2010 14:33:14.55* w3wp.exe (0x0828)                           0x1AFC  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...n(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   4015c593-b9b1-4141-815e-82fc55777208
```

**Update** based on question from Wictor:

No changes were made to the pages manually or through UI or SPD2010.

Comment: Quite weird that this shows up if you haven't changed anything, the error is straightforward, you have two controls with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made any changes to the User Profile Properties? Check if there are multiple properties named **AccountName**.